# Kubuntu cannot switch from Nvidia to Intel driver

Tags: drivers, nvidia, kubuntu, 17.10, intel-graphics

I'm running Kubuntu 17.10 (latest updates at the time of writing).

Everything works fine, but when I try switching from the Nvidia card to the Intel one (for energy reasons), the option - which *seems* available - in Nvidia X server settings just doesn't work.

Meaning I can click it, but it doesn't "stay selected", in lack of better words.

No syslog entry associated to the click.

A related issue, maybe: in Driver Manager, I if I activate the checkbox stating: `Using Processor microcode firmware for Intel CPUs from intel-microcode` and click `Apply`, the checkbox stays un-checked after refreshing.

This doesn't come with any useful syslog entry either, aside from `DriverManager_DBus::devices START` and `DriverManager_DBus::devices END`.

**Hardware and drivers**

- KDE Plasma version 5.10.5
- KDE Frameworks version 5.38.0
- Qt version 5.9.1
- Kernel version 4.13.0-32-generic
- 64 bit
- Output of `lspci | grep VGA`

> 00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 591b (rev
>   04)
>
> 01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GP106M
>   [GeForce GTX 1060 Mobile] (rev a1)

- Nvidia driver version: 384.111 (proprietary - I think?)

I've seen a lot of posts regarding Graphics cards and issues with various desktops, but haven't found any existing one that can help me.

**TL;DR**

How do I switch to Intel graphics for power saving in Kubuntu 17.10?

**Edit**

Switching ACPI off for PCI in the kernel parameters on boot (`pci=noacpi`) seems to force the Intel driver, but I suspect this won't play well with other PCI-related features, such as power metrics and even shutting down, rebooting, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Found a very ugly solution - I hope there will be better answers.

It looks like package `intel-microcode` was not installed on Kubuntu by default for me (weird).

Once installed (`sudo apt-get intel-microcode`), I was able to set up NVIDIA X Server Settings to use the Intel card.

Now comes the ugliness.

1. Since the power button applet in KDE ("ksmserver-logout-greeter") doesn't seem to like VGA device changes, I had to `sudo reboot now` from terminal, which somehow ended up shutting down the machine instead of rebooting
2. Then, apparently something related to ACPI didn't quite work with my selected Intel card, so I had to restart again and parametrize the kernel with `pci=noacpi`

Now I am correctly using the Intel VGA device, but the steps to do so aren't particularly practical (let alone the possible implications of `pci-noacpi`).

So far, operations such as shutdown, reboot and logout seem to work with the Intel card selected.